# OpsCenter graphs are slow to refresh, can I configure the refresh rate?

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I am new to OpsCenter and trying to get a feel for the metric graphs.  The graphs seem slow to refresh and I'm trying to determine if this is a configuration issue on my part or simply what to expect.

For example, I have a three node Cassandra test cluster created via CCM. OpsCenter and the node Agents were configured manually.

I have graphs on the dashboard for Read and Write Requests and Latency.  I'm running a JMeter test that inserts 100k rows into a Cassandra table (via REST calls to my webapp) over the course of about 5 minutes.

I have both  OpsCenter and VisualVm open. When the test kicks off, **VisualVM graphs immediately start showing the change in load (via Heap and CPU/GC graphs) but the OpsCenter graphs lag behind and are slow to update.**  I realize I'm comparing different metrics (ie. Heap vs Write Requests) but I would expect to see some immediate indication in OpsCenter that a load is being applied.

My environment is as follows:

- Cassandra: dsc-cassandra-2.1.2
- OpsCenter: opscenter-5.1.0
- Agents: datastax-agent-5.1.0
- OS: OSX 10.10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently metrics are collected every 60 seconds, plus there’s a (albeit very small) overhead on inserting them into C*, reading back on the OpsCenter server side, and pushing to the UI.

OpsCenter team is working on both improving metrics collection in general and on delivering realtime metrics, so stay tuned.

By the way, comparing VisualVM and OpsCenter in terms of latencies is not quite correct since OpsCenter has to do a lot more work to both collect and aggregate those metrics due to its distributed nature (and also because VisualVM is so close to the meta^WJVM ;)